# Get the list of keys where the values are equal for those keys

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, sortedmap

I require to get the list of keys where the values are equal for those keys from a HashMap.
For example , my hashmap contains the below elements.

```
Key  Value
1    a,b
2    e,c
3    a,b
4    f
5    e,c
6    c
```

We need to evaluate as

```
1,3 contains value (a,b)  
2,5 contains value (e,c)  
4   contains value (f)  
6   contains value (c)
```

Thx

Comment: post the code you have tried so far and where you're stuck

Answer (score 3):

You could invert your hash: build a new hash with the key type being the type of your current map's value, and the value type being a list of your current map's key type.

Iterate over your current map's keys, and push them to the right slot in your new map. You'll then have exactly the mapping you are asking for.

If the values in your current map aren't directly comparable right now, you'll need to find a representation that is. This depends completely on the nature of the data.
One simple approach is to sort the list and use it's `toString` representation as your new key. This only works if the `toString` representation of the underlying objects is sane for this purpose.

Comment: Thx Mat .. I too thought of it but in this case , the key itself is a list so how it will work . The keys are treated as different even though it has same value ..can you please give code snippet ?

Comment: Are the keys or _values_ (of your current map) a list?

Comment: The values of the current HashMap is a list

Comment: @JavaUser - you don't need a code snippet.  Mat's answer is sufficiently detailed to be implemented directly.  (SO is not a "write my code for me for free" service.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create other map where your keys a used as values and values as keys. If for example your source map is defined as `Map<Integer, String>` create map `Map<String, List<Integer>>`. The list of integers will contain keys (from your source map) that have certain values.

Comment: Yes Alex ..Mat also suggested the same idea. Can you give me code snippet . I guess it wont work as I mentioned for Mats comment.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mat's answer, if you need to do this operation frequently, use one of the bidirectional map classes from Guava or Apache Commons Collections; e.g. [`HashBiMap<K,V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) or `DualHashBidiMap` or [`DualTreeBidiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/DualTreeBidiMap.html).  These data structures *maintain* a pair of maps that represent the forward and inverse mappings.

Alternatively, for a once off computation:

1. Extract the `Map.entries()` collection into an array.
2. Sort the array in order of the values.
3. Iterate the array, and extract the entry keys for which subsequent entry values are equal.

(This should be `O(NlogN)` in time and require `O(N)` extra space ... depending on the sort algorithm used.)

Comment: I am restricted to use those APIS

Comment: Stephen . this is one time operation .

Comment: @JavaUser - in that case, here are a couple more hints.  1) There is a method in the `Collection` API to copy the elements to an array.  2) The `Arrays` class has a static method that will sort an array.  3) You will need to create and use a custom `Comparator` to sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic method will be to:

1. Get the first key of the `HashMap` and iterate over the map checking for keys with the same value.
2. If found, remove that key from the map and store the key in another collection (maybe a `Vector`).
3. Then after all other keys are checked, add the current key to that collection.
4. If no other keys are found, add the current key to that collection.
5. Then add the keys in that collection to another map with the relevant value. Clear the collection.
6. Proceed to the next key and do the same.

After doing this, you will end up with what you want.

EDIT: The Code:

```
    HashMap comp = new HashMap(); // Calculations Done
    Vector v = new Vector(); // Temporary List To Store Keys

    // Get The List Of Keys
    Vector<Integer> keys = new Vector<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> it = hm.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) keys.add(it.next());

    // For Every Key In Map...
    for(int i = 0; i < hm.size(); i++) {
        int key = keys.get(i);
        v.add(key);  // Add the Current Key To Temporary List

        // Check If Others Exist
        for(int j = i+1; j < hm.size(); j++) {
            int nkey = keys.get(j);
            if(hm.get(key).equals(hm.get(nkey))) {
                v.add(nkey);
            }
        }

        // Store The Value Of Current Key And The Keys In Temporary List In The Comp HashMap
        String val = hm.get(key);
        String cKey = "";
        for(int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++)
            cKey += v.get(x) + ",";

        // Remove The Comma From Last Key, Put The Keys As Value And Value As Key
        cKey = cKey.substring(0, cKey.length()-1);
        comp.put(cKey, val);

        // Clear The Temporary List
        v.clear();
    }
```

There is a little problem in this code: Duplicates occur and also the last duplicate seems to be correct.

The output using your example give. (You need to do a little formatting).

```
{3=a,b, 6=c, 5=e,c, 2,5=e,c, 4=f, 1,3=a,b}
```

Comment: This is `O(N^2)` and it destroys the original `HashMap`.

Comment: @StephenC Umm, what exactly is `O(N^2)`? I think its something to with algorithms, but what exactly is it?

Comment: It means that the time to process the map is proportional to `N * N`, where `N` is the number of entries in the map.

Comment: @Roshnal - I should also point out that it is not in the long term interest of a student to provide him / her code that they can copy and paste as their homework solution.  Now, we don't *know* that this is a homework problem, but there are (IMO) strong signs that it is.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the explanation! And sorry I didn't realize it was homework, but I'll be careful in the future.